# Juntar um plot e uma imagem em matlab

Tags: imagem, matlab, processamento-de-imagens

Estou a realizar um trabalho de processamento de imagem médica que pretende isolar a zona dos pulmões e colocar um contorno.
Isolei a zona correspondente aos pulmões e criei um plot com os contornos. A minha dúvida é como poderei juntar a imagem com o plot, de modo a obter a imagem com os contornos que é pedida.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem você precisa de um `hold on` para manter os dois plots juntos...

É bem simples, para demonstrar eu vou utilizar o seguinte sinal de áudio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora eu vou aplicar um algoritmo para extrair informações sobre onde ocorre a abertura da [glote](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glote) neste sinal e obtenho o seguinte plot:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perfeito agora eu quero juntar as imagens, então eu faço isso:

```
figure(1)
plot(sinal)
hold on
plot(glote)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fique atenta para que o eixo `X` de ambos os plotes estejam com o mesmo tamanho, se uma for diferente da outra você vai precisar recortar o pedaço de um ou interpolar para que ambos fiquem do mesmo tamanho. Como você esta trabalhando com imagens (matriz) você pode definir onde plotar encima de uma imagem apontando a linha e coluna para uma posição de pixel da imagem.

Um exemplo bem simples para imagem é este:

```
imagesc(img);
hold on
scatter(10,40);
```

Neste exemplo estou plotando um circulo encima da imagem na linha 10 e coluna 40.

Aqui um link bem interessante, http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/matlab/plot_over_image_background

Espero que seja isso que precise.